# Writing a Union function to implement Java Sets

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

As a part of an exercise, I have to implement sets in Java using a linked list. I'm having a bit of trouble in implementing the Union function to return a generic set.

```
public class Myset<T> {
    //Some fields and methods 

    public Myset<T> Union(Myset<T> a) {
        Myset<T> result = new Myset<T>(); //The set that stores the resultant set

        //Some code to compute the union

        return result;
    }
}
```

Now, when I try to use this set on a specific class, I encounter a problem.

```
public class IntSet extends Myset<Integer> {
   //Some methods and fields

   public IntSet increment() {
       IntSet temp = new IntSet();
       //Makes a new IntSet temp whose elements are one obtained by adding 1 to each element of the current set
       return temp;
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      IntSet a = new IntSet();
      IntSet b = new IntSet();
      IntSet c = a.Union(b).increment();
   }
}
```

If I try to call a method defined in `IntSet` on `a.Union(b)` where `a, b` are instances of `IntSet`, I encounter an error saying that `Myset<Integer>` cannot be converted to an `IntSet`. Trying to cast gives a run-time error. How do I get around this issue?

**EDIT:** The error here occurs when I call the `increment()` operation (which is defined only in the subclass `IntSet`) on the `Myset<Integer>` given by `a.Union(b)`.

Comment: What is the runtime error?

Comment: @arturios The code compiles. If I try to call some method of `IntSet` on `a.Union(b)` then Java throws an exception and the program terminates.

Comment: Can you paste the exception here?

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException: Myset<Integer> cannot be cast to IntSet`

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to cast the parent class to the child class you could only do the inverse.

Comment: Yes, I'm perfectly aware of that. My question is, is there any other way in which I can implement a generic Myset with the specifications above?

Comment: Can you post more code?  What code throws the exception?

Comment: @AndrewS: Posted

Comment: `union()` doesn't return an `IntSet` (as @arturios suggested).  Consider using composition instead of inheritance,

Answer (score 0):

```
class Myset<K, T> {

    public Set<T> set = new HashSet<>();

    public void setSet(Set<T> newSet) {
        this.set = newSet;
    }

    public <K extends Myset> K Union(Class<K> clazz, K val) {
        try {
            K newSet = clazz.newInstance();
            /// union code
            newSet.setSet(set);
            return newSet;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class IntSet extends Myset<IntSet, Integer> {
    // your functions
}

public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        IntSet temp = new IntSet();
        IntSet temp2 = new IntSet();
        IntSet merge = temp.Union(IntSet.class, temp2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class MySet<T, E extends MySet> {

    public E union(MySet a) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        E result = (E) this.getClass().newInstance(); //The set that stores the resultant set
        //Some code to compute the union
        return result;
    }
}
```

And ..

```
public class InSet extends MySet<Integer, InSet> {

    public InSet increment() {
        InSet temp = new InSet();
        //Makes a new IntSet temp whose elements are one obtained by adding 1 to each element of the current set
        return temp;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        InSet a = new InSet();
        InSet b = new InSet();
        InSet c = a.union(b).increment();
    }
}
```